# INSERT INTO returns ERROR 1452

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to move data from one table to another, but having an error:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO activities_article (category_id, created_at, title, promo, content, promo_image_url, coordinates, vk_id, updated_at, hot)
SELECT category_id, created_at, title, promo, content, promo_image_url, coordinates, vk_id, NOW(), False 
FROM dorogirussia.activities_article WHERE category_id=4;

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dorogi`.`activities_article`, CONSTRAINT `activities_articl_category_id_632c9272_fk_activities_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `activities_category` (`id`))
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I take it you've read the error message and checked to see if there's a given row in `activities_category` with a relevant `id` ?

Comment: I have a row with `id=4` in `activities_category`

Comment: In fact, my question was stupid, seeing as it's a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` the same table

Comment: It's not the exact same table. I move data from one database to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have the value "4" in "id" column in `dorogi`.`activities_category` and also change the query to the following:

```
INSERT INTO dorogi.activities_article (category_id, created_at, title, promo, content, promo_image_url, coordinates, vk_id, updated_at, hot)
SELECT category_id, created_at, title, promo, content, promo_image_url, coordinates, vk_id, NOW(), False 
FROM dorogirussia.activities_article WHERE category_id=4;
```

Hope this solves your problem !!